# How can I break a python data analytics code into modules?

Tags: python, analytics, data-analysis, data-science

I am a business intelligence analyst starting with data analysis using python.

I am in the early stage of coding a marketing analytics App for internal use (marketing analysts) without the need to use MS Excel for calculations.

The main goals are:

1. Prompt asking to select raw file
2. Read csv/xlsx data
3. Clean (drop nulls, drop total rows, format numbers and dates, etc.)
4. Transform (create metrics like cost per click, per thousand
       impressions , per leads, return of ad spend, in each channel like
       facebook, youtube, google search and so on)
5. Analysis (Highlight the best and worst performances by channel, type
       of goal, url, etc)   Load (print in the screen and write on a xlsx
       file)

For now I have broke the project into two files: **main.py** (main functions and prints) and **data_prep.py** (functions related with data cleasing and transformation).

I believe that there must be a framework or some model of break the files in a logical and organized way and I want to apply this in the early stages to avoid rework and build a more reliable and easy to maintain application.

**PS: In this thread I am concerned with the file/directories structure, not the libraries that I need to use.**

Comment: You probably want to check out http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: Are you trying to build a web based UI for number 1? If so, you will need to handle the upload in the front end. For number 2 and 3 you can use the following libraries: csv (comes with python), xlrd (for reading excel files that may have formatting) and pandas (will be helpful for the majority of your task). For numbers 3-5, pandas will probably be the most useful library. You can read more about it here: http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: I feel like I am missing your question here.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.K. SandPiper, I added a note that might clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the file location is consistent (shared folder, cluster folder, web service API-derived location), I don't think there's a 'best' way to organize your files or directories. Be clear in your labeling and you should be able to pull all your data together in one place. A file structure like:

```
/Marketing/Analysis/dev/
  ./source <- for csv files to be kept
  ./prog <- for your .py files (actual code)
  ./result <- output from your process
  ./notes <- for anything non-functional (ie, release notes or project requests)
```

Do you have a stash or bitbucket repo for your code? If so, use that for scratchwork and keep only your current code in ./prog.

If you're pulling in GoogleAnalytics, you may want to try making API calls directly from Python rather than downloading csv files to ./source. It'll just reduce the number of variables by one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm using bitbucket.